# Botão que aciona o subscribe só funciona no segundo click

Tags: angular

Tenho um botão para cada linha de uma grid, que ao ser clicado, chama um subscribe que preenche os dados daquele código clicado dentro de um modal.
Esse botão até que funciona, mas não no primeiro clique, e sim no segundo.
Mas ao mover esse subscribe para dentro do `ngOnInit`, o botão funciona no primeiro clique, mas quando eu entro no meu sistema a pagina demora muito pra carregar.
Imagino que seja um tempo de espera pra carregar os dados, mas não sei como resolver isso.

Meu botão chama a função `clickDetail()`

```html
<a type="button" #modal data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" (click)="clickDetail()"></a>
```

Meu arquivo TS

```html
clickDetail () {
  this.diarioCarteiraService.getCarteiras(this.codigoCarteira).subscribe(res => {
    this.listaCarteira = res.data;   
  });
}
```

Meu Service

```html
getCarteiras(codigoCarteira: number): Observable<ResponseDiarioCarteira> {
  return this.http.get<ResponseDiarioCarteira>(`${this.urlApi}/${'diario- carteira?codigo='}${codigoCarteira}`, super.ObterAuthHeader());
}
```

Comment: Seria pertinente informar maiores detalhes a pergunta como o Html do **modal**, assim também como se dá algum erro no console!

Answer (score -2):

Vendo seu código eu suponho que haja algum conflito entre o Angular e o Bootstrap. Você já testou não usar a tag <a> como toggle para o modal do bootstrap? Se não, teste, talvez seja isso.

Caso esse seja o problema a solução é você abrir o modal programaticamente, usando, por exemplo, o subscribe do retorno do método getCarteiras.

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta, eu até já tentei usar o button, mas acontece a mesma coisa. 
Como sou nova nesse mundo do angular eu não sabia q dava para abrir o modal no subscribe.
Pode me mostrar como faz?

Comment: Veja se esse link te ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42893918/how-do-i-toggle-bootstrap-4-modal-using-angular2-component-typescript

Comment: Quanto a resposta, eu propus que você removesse todas as classes e atributos do modal da tag <a>, e não que usasse button, porque dessa forma você pode saber se o problema está em alguma incompatibilidade. O bootstrap usa o onclick do elemento para abrir o modal, talvez isso esteja conflitando com o (click)

Answer (score -3):

Eu gostaria de responder no formato de comentário, mas não tenho reputação pra isso ainda.

A melhor coisa de momento era que você disponibilizasse mais detalhes da implementação, inclusive do modal.

Com o seu relato e com os detalhes de implementação já disponibilizados, o meu palpite seria que o modal está aparecendo antes de que os dados estejam carregados e por algum detalhe da implementação eles não estão sendo exibidos.

Creio que seja algo simples de ser ajustado, tipo só aquele "pulo do gato". Aguardo um update da sua pergunta [@lipascoal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/179609/lipascoal).